# Let $\{A_n\}_n$ be a sequence of measure sets, show $\mu(\lim \inf A_n) \le \lim \inf \mu(A_n)$.

Tags: measure-theory

I want to use Fatou's Lemma to show that $\mu(\lim \inf A_n) \le \lim \inf \mu(A_n)$.
My claim is
\begin{equation*}
        \mu(\lim \inf \chi_{A_n})=\int \lim \inf \chi_{A_n} d\mu \le \lim \inf \int \chi_{A_n} d\mu= \lim \inf  \mu(A_n).  
        \end{equation*}
My question is: Is true that $\mu(\lim \inf \chi_{A_n})=\int \lim \inf \chi_{A_n} d\mu$? Thanks a lot!

Comment: On LHS you write $\mu(\liminf \chi_{A_n})$. That should be changed into $\mu(\liminf A_n)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It holds that (the LHS is $1$ iff the RHS is $1$ and LHS is $0$ iff the RHS is $0$)

$$\chi_{\{\liminf A_n\}}=\liminf \chi_{A_n}$$

Taking integrals allows you to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Write $g(x)=\liminf \chi_{A_{n}}(x)$ and if you show $g$ is a measurable function, then you are done.

Comment: How does this answer the question? "Rename something and then you are done"??

Comment: It's a way of framing the problem